# How to loop arrays into csv with Python?

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am trying to loop multiple arrays and write them into csv file with under right filednames.

Here is the working code but is is bad approach and not professional:

```
# zip arrays
  rows = zip(en,pl,tr,de)    

# Write to CSV
  with open('translations.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['English', 'Polish', 'Turkish', 'German']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in rows:
      info  = inspect.getmembers(row)
      english = row[0]
      polish = row[1]
      turkish = row[2]
      german = row[3]
      writer.writerow({'English': english, 'Polish':polish, 'Turkish':turkish, 'German':german})
```

I tried to change the code and it is really messed up:

```
# zip arrays
 rows = zip(en,pl,tr,de)  

# Write to CSV
  with open('translations.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['English', 'Polish', 'Turkish', 'German']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in rows:
      for i in range(len(fieldnames)):
        writer.writerow({fieldnames[i]:row[i]})
```

So every translation should under right filedname. Here the result of this code:

```
English,Polish,Turkish,German
Test Name,,,
,Test Name,,
,,Test Name,
,,,Test Name
Nazwa testu,,,
,Nazwa testu,,
,,Nazwa testu,
,,,Nazwa testu
test Adı,,,
,test Adı,,
,,test Adı,
,,,test Adı
Testname,,,
,Testname,,
,,Testname,
,,,Testname
```

It is really messed up. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need this. Instead of

```
for i in range(len(fieldnames)):
    writer.writerow({fieldnames[i]:row[i]})
```

Use:

```
    writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, row)))
```

Comment: You are legend! Thank you very much :)